# Class MongoDB not found

Tags: php, mongodb, driver

I have followed this document to install mongodb driver.
http://php.net/manual/en/mongodb.installation.php.php.
However, when I init a new manager. The class is not found.

> PHP Fatal error:  Class 'MongoDB\Driver\Manager' not found

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the problem. If you use the old mongo driver (mongo.so). It will cause the problem.
So just remove the extension=mongo.so in your configuration file.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

As a  solution to your above mentioned issue please check the configuration of php through executing **phpinfo()** function into php script

In output of **phpinfo()** please verify whether section of **mongo** exists or not

If non existent then mongo driver is not properly configured into php.

In that scenario please determine whether **mongodb.so (Linux)** or **php_mongodb.dll (Windows)** dependent upon server environment exists into location defined in **extension_dir configuration option in php.ini**

Comment: In your answer, you should change mongo to mongodb.
That's what I have misunderstood. The mongodb driver is different from mongo extension.

Comment: @DatTran I referred to mongo section as described in above snapshot

Comment: The one you snapshot is the mongo extension, which PHP manual said that "This extension is deprecated. Instead, the MongoDB extension should be used.": http://php.net/manual/en/mongo.installation.php.

And the one I'm talking about is the new one: http://php.net/manual/en/mongodb.installation.php.php